# RegEX replace in Visual Studio, what would be the method to do so?

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I am adjusting a variable, generally it has become

Sessions(ID).Player

to

PlayerList(Sessions(ID).PlayerIndex)

Obviously if ID was the same in all cases, it would be a easy replacement, however, ID changes, so it might be Sessions(foundID).Player for example as well.

I am wondering how to use basic regular expressions to replace the variables so that Sessions(ID).Player becomes PlayerList(Sessions(ID).PlayerIndex) OR Sessions(foundID).Player becomes PlayerList(Sessions(foundID).PlayerIndex)..

Is there any way to do this? Also, what is a good regex site for beginners? There is alot of information online but sometimes I feel the patterns are different depending on the program you use. I'm not sure why this occurs either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have it.

Sessions((.+)).Player

and replace with

PlayerList(Sessions($1).PlayerIndex)

Seems to do it. Sorry for taking up everyone time! Hopefully I can continue without problems. Regex seems powerful.

Comment: Ah actually, that replaces almost works but not quite yet.

Call LocalSendMessage(Sessions(Index).Player.CurrentRoom, 1, "~yFrom~w " & Sessions(Index).Player.CharAlias & "~y: " & Data)

The above finds

Sessions(Index).Player.CurrentRoom, 1, "~yFrom~w " & Sessions(Index).Player   which is finding more than one instance per line.

Comment: Sessions((.*?)).Player  should work actually. Got it!